# SubCut BindingModule composition

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, subcut

With SubCut I can define a BindingModule and use [modifyBindings](https://github.com/dickwall/subcut/blob/master/GettingStarted.md) to get a new one which can overwrite some bindings and also add new bindings. Is there a utility where instead of saying

```
val module : BindingModule
val newModule = module.modifBindings(...)
```

I could instead do something like

```
val mergedModule = merge(module1,module2,module3,...)
```

The reason is I am writing an application with **"pluggable"** jars - each such jar will have a *META-INF/bindings.properties* file which will expose the class name of its *BindingModule*. My main entry jar will instantiate those *BindingModules* via reflection and then combine them.

The idea being that if the pluggable jars follow the convention of providing *META-INF/bindings.properties* then there is no new configuration needed  to deploy the application.

Comment: We found a way to declare modules as traits and then merge them whereby they would resolve any interdependencies by mixing in. However I can't mix in traits using reflection, can I?

Comment: By the way, the "can I?" part above is rhetorical.

Comment: You might want to try Sindi instead of SubCut. It can handle dependencies between binding modules; whether it would work with reflection I'm not sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use the ~ operator, as shown in [this test case from the SubCut project](https://github.com/dickwall/subcut/blob/c54f1f83cd595e28c0d4b323573571c12c40f4a7/src/test/scala/org/scala_tools/subcut/inject/ModuleCompositionAndMergingTest.scala).

For the case of interdependent modules, please expand your question with more details on how you implemented that.