# How to integrate subcut dependent modules?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, subcut

Based on available documentation this task seems straightforward, however I've been hitting my head in the wall for a couple of days on this and still can't make it work for a simple inter-module dependency...

Here's a reduced example:

```
trait Bla {
  def m: String
}

class BlaImpl(implicit val bindingModule: BindingModule) extends Bla with Injectable {
  val s = inject[String]('bla)
  def m = "got " + s
}

object Program extends App with Injectable {
  implicit val bindingModule =
    new NewBindingModule({ implicit module ⇒ module.bind[Bla] toSingle { new BlaImpl } }) ~
      new NewBindingModule(_.bind[String] idBy 'bla toSingle "bla!")
  val bla = inject[Bla]
  assert(bla.m == "got bla!")
}
```

Running this code fails with the following error, When trying to build the BlaImpl instance:

```
 org.scala_tools.subcut.inject.BindingException: No binding for key BindingKey(java.lang.String,Some(bla))
```

Debugging shows that the binding module handed to BlaImpl's constructor doesn't contain the 'bla String in its bindings, and that Program.bindingModule.bindings has all bindings (including the needed String).

I've seen [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303262/subcut-bindingmodule-composition) similar but it dows refer only to composition but not to dependencies crossing module borders.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it will not work. Even if you merge 2 modules together 
with subcut, this does not mean that they will see each-others dependencies.

If you want to archive desired results, then you need to pass `BindingModule` explicitly to the  `BlaImpl` constructor. Something like this:

```
val anotherModule = new NewBindingModule(_.bind[String] idBy 'bla toSingle "bla!")

implicit val bindingModule =
  new NewBindingModule({ implicit module => module.bind[Bla] toSingle { new BlaImpl()(anotherModule) } })
```

Module merge will not do the trick in this case. I actually discussed this problem of subcut in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646571/comparing-subcut-and-scaldi/16660055#16660055). I even created a example code that compares subcut and [Scaldi](http://scaldi.github.io/scaldi/Scaldi.html) and demonstrates how they both solve this problem (or don't solve it, in case of subcut):

https://gist.github.com/OlegIlyenko/5623423

If I would rewrite your example with [Scaldi](http://scaldi.github.io/scaldi/Scaldi.html), then it would be something like this:

```
import scaldi.{Injector, Injectable, Module, DynamicModule}

trait Bla {
  def m: String
}

class BlaImpl(implicit inj: Injector) extends Bla with Injectable {
  val s = inject[String]('bla)
  def m = "got " + s
}

object Program extends App with Injectable {
  implicit val appModule =
    new Module { bind [Bla] to new BlaImpl } ::
    DynamicModule(_.binding identifiedBy 'bla to "bla!")

  val bla = inject [Bla]
  assert(bla.m == "got bla!")
}
```

As you can see, in [Scaldi](http://scaldi.github.io/scaldi/Scaldi.html) modules can see each-others dependencies if they are composed with `::` or `++`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've given up on Subcut a long time ago  because of this and some other issues and went with the cake pattern alone. To be honest, I wasn't aware of Scaldi but I will be looking at it when I have the available time needed.

Comment: WRT cake pattern, I must tell that you easily become in love with having the compiler telling you whether you have your components' deps satisfied or not.